# Android Picasso Reload Image from cache fail

Tags: android, caching, picasso, image-loading

Its been sometime I  started using Picasso for Image Loading in Android. The usual scenario  is , it downloads images and cache it and if later needed it retrieves from Cache.

just found this use case,

if the ImageURL ends with .(jpg,png, etc etc .....)

Ex:http://www.androidguys.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/android-for-wallpaper-8.png

Picasso work as expected , 
but if the imageURL's are of type
http://cloud.clubsalive.com.au/download/33/404e58cf-d890-4eaa-981e-c2f3442f9348

then its not reloading from cache , its downloading every time when the view is loaded.
Is it a normal behavior of Picasso ???

Answer (score 0):

Your image is giant. Try to increase cache size. Or scale down your image